# I'm migrating a flutter app to 3.10.6 and I encountered an error in sqflite, the result in the app is sorted which shouldn't be

Tags: flutter, sqflite

The version of SQFLITE I'm using is 2.2.8+4

When I run my query from the DB Browser it's sorted in the way I want it (without using sorting functions), but when I run the query in the app it is sorted.

Is there a way to make the sqflite result the same as DB Browser's result?